# Have Plesk read user defined logfiles

Tags: plesk, logfile, logfile-analysis

Plesk offers the possibility of adding user defined log files to the protocol under Logs. What format should these user defined log files be in in order to show them as:

| Date | Type | IP | Code | Message | Agent | Size | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-07 09:53:14 | Info | 127.0.0.5 | 99 | Opening log |  |  | app.log |

so that they fit snuggly with the other log files?